# Can't align items to center using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have tried everything I know, and I can not get my items to align center. I have one large container shown below...

```
.container2 {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: linear-gradient(80deg, black, rgb(221, 198, 134));
  width: 95%;
}
```

This is a large container displaying everything I want in a column which is how I want it. Then I have images at the bottom of "container2" that I need to be displayed in-line, heres the code below...

```
.photo-container {
  display: inline-block;
  /* margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%; */
}
```

I have tried many different ways and I can't seem to get it to work. Here below is the actual img elements...

```
.photo-container img {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div className="container2">
<div className="photo-container">
          <img src={Barber.image1}></img>
          <img src={Barber.image2}></img>
          <img src={Barber.image3}></img>
          <img src={Barber.image4}></img>
          <img src={Barber.image5}></img>
          <img src={Barber.image6}></img>
        </div>
      
</div>
```

the "left: 50%" sets the .photo-container outside of the "container2", not sure why it does that as I thought position relative sets it relative to its parent. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: @TannerDolby yes i have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `text-align: center` on the `photo-container` to get all images in center.

```css
.container2 {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: linear-gradient(80deg, black, rgb(221, 198, 134));
  width: 95%;
 
}

.photo-container {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="photo-container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png"></img>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png"></img>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png"></img>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png"></img>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png"></img>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png"></img>
  </div>

</div>
```